# rest-assured return empty string when using spring reactor

Tags: spring, mono, flux, rest-assured, project-reactor

I am using rest assured mvn with spring+reactor. But rest assured mvc on my testes does not work well when my controllers returns Mono or Flux objects. When i call response.getBody().asString() it returns a empty string (""), if i change the controller to return my object instead of a mono it works.

Thanks